# Finding the max value given table

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So I was given the following prompt:

> Let $f$ be a function having derivatives for all orders of real numbers. The function and its first four derivatives at $x=0$ are given in the table below. The $5$th derivative of $f$ satisfies the inequality $|f^{(5)}(x)|\leq160$ for all $x$ in the interval $[0, 2]$. Find the maximum value of $f(3/2)$.

[image]

So I understand how I'd go about finding a Taylor polynomial from the table, but I'm a bit confused about how I'd have to use this value to find what they're looking for in the question. I thought about using this polynomial with the Taylor's remainder equation to try and approximate $f(\frac{3}{2})$, but I don't know if that's right or not. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Absolutely.  Use Taylor's formula with remainder.

Comment: How would I find the $f(z)$ value in the remainder equation here?

Comment: @joe Read the theorem. Tell us which part of the formula you find confusing.

Comment: I'm confused given the remainder formula is: $|R_n(x)|\leq|\frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}*(x-a)^n|$, I'm confused over how I'd go about finding $f^{(n)}(z)$ here.

Comment: @joe Does "$|f^{(5)}(x)|\leq160$ for all $x$ in the interval $[0, 2]$" ring any bells? You're not after any exact values. Only bounds.

Comment: So wait, then how would I find the remainder only given bounds?

Comment: You're asked to find _bounds_ on the value at $x=\frac32$. Finding a bound on the remainder term will accomplish that. And since we have a bound on the fifth derivative, ...

Comment: I'm still confused over what it would be then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the correct idea. You can approximate
$$
f(x) = T(x) + R(x),
$$
where $T(x)$ is the fourth order Taylor polynomial, and $R(x)$ is the remainder term, which can be bounded by $f^{(5)}(a) x^5$ for some $a$. Can you finish?

---

You can check out section 2 in the Wiki article on [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), especially the subsection 2.4 which has an example.

---

**UPDATE**

Using the Mean-value estimate for the remainder, you will get
$$
f(x) = T(x) + f^{(4)}(x) \frac{x^4}{4!}
$$
so
$$
f(3/2) = T(3/2) + f^{(4)}(3/2) \frac{(3/2)^4}{4!}
 \le \left| f^{(4)}(3/2)\right| \frac{(3/2)^4}{4!}
$$

Can you now use your upper bound and finish the estimate?

Comment: I'm confused over what the $f(z)$ value would look like in the application of the Taylor's remainder formula here, how would I go about finding that?

Comment: @joe you don't need to find it, you are given an upper bound on $f^{(n)}(z)$

Comment: I'm still confused, what would the remainder be then?

Comment: @joe please see the update

Comment: I'm so sorry I'm still a bit confused, where would I be using my "upper bound" would it be plugged in for the $f^{(4)}(\frac{3}{2})$ term?

Comment: @joe yes, you have an upper bound for $\left| f^{(4)}(3/2)\right|$